# Illegal instruction (core dumped) docker, red hat 7.7, aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, redhat

I have this issue in AWS EC2 Red hat 7.7 where docker containers stop working with illegal instruction core dumped error, especially during startup time. I have tried everything but I am unable to find out why. It is intermittent but I don't know why it happens. I checked memory, CPU, system logs, storage, tried different versions of container images but I am unable to find the root cause of this error.

Can anyone help troubleshoot or point me in a direction where I can investigate more?
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You mean the docker daemon itself, or a container you are running via docker?

Comment: @jordanm the docker container errors out with illegal instruction core dumped, I see this behavior nginx1.15.2 + and python containers as of now. I am out of options, any help will be great

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the core dump with gdb?